# Multiple instances of isFetching in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reducer which is accessed through `state.posts.x`

It looks like this:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_PUBLISHED_POSTS_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true
        }
    case FETCH_PUBLISHED_POSTS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            publishedPosts: action.publishedPosts,
            isFetching: false
        }
    case FETCH_SINGLE_POST_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true
        }
    case FETCH_SINGLE_POST_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            singlePost: action.singlePost,
            isFetching: false
        }
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Inside my component I am mapping state to props to check for isFetching. The problem I'm having is that isFetching gets changed to "true" whenever either publishedPosts or singlePost is called, so my UI is showing loading state when it shouldn't.

What are the best practice ways to get around this? It makes no sense to split this into two reducers. It also seems counter-productive to change the name of isFetching to make it unique (i.e. isFetchingPublishedPosts).

Comment: `whenever either publishedPosts or singlePost` which are the action,there are two actions

Answer (score 1):

Your component should only receive the part of the state it's concerned about. If `isFetching` is not supposed to affect the component, then strip it out of your component's `mapStateToProps` function:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ myprop: state.importantStateForTheComponent })
```

In this example, if you have an `importantStateForTheComponent` field in the state, your component will receive as prop, but it will ignore any change to `state.isFetching`.

Comment: My reducer is exported as "posts" and when called using mapStateToProps isFetching is brought in like this: isFetching: state.posts.isFetching

Comment: I could get around this issue by making each field in the reducer unique, i.e. by changing from isFetching to isFetchingPublishedPosts... but it seems laborious

Comment: It depends on what you're using the flag for. In this case you would probably want to have different flags for different type of requests, as you suggest.

Comment: @MattSaunders It's laborious but the only way the keep the design clean. Redux is verbose in that sense, but you gain simplicity in the components as a tradeoff. Another appraoch would be to split the state in `{ published: {...}, single: {...} }`. Fetching either type of post could also result in different errors for example that you might want to display.